# Como atribui valor do Fetch em uma variável

Tags: javascript

tenho o seguinte código abaixo

```js
 dia_do_mes = {};

  fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/dhhvz')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(r => {
    console.log(r)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
  })
```

Minha única dúvida é, como eu faço para atribui a resposta no JSON na no 'r', tipo pelo console log eu vejo o objeto retornando corretamente, mas quando tento atribui o 'r' a váriavel dia_do_mes = {};, não funciona, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: A atribuição deveria funcionar normalmente. O único detalhe que precisa cuidar é de não utilizar a variável antes que a requisição seja finalizada. A ideia é que, sendo assíncrono, você faça o que precisa fazer com o JSON no próprio `then`. Por que precisa atribuir à variável?

Comment: Você quer atribuir o response para a variável dia_do_mes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thiago, quando você trabalhar com requisições, normalmente elas tem o comportamento assíncrono, por conta disso você não consegue efetuar essa atribuição direta.

Uma opção seria trabalhar com async/await, também seria possível atribuir o valor somente no then do retorno da variável r, entre outras possibilidades:

```js
// Exemplo com async/await
let dia_do_mes = {};

(async () => {
    dia_do_mes = await fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/dhhvz')
        .then(response => {
        return response.json();
        })
        .then(r => {
             return r;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // Do something for an error here
        });
    console.log("Exemplo com async/await", dia_do_mes);
})();

// Exemplo pegando o valor no bloco then do retorno r
let outro_dia_do_mes = {};

fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/dhhvz')
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(r => {
         outro_dia_do_mes = r;
         console.log("Exemplo no bloco do then", outro_dia_do_mes);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Do something for an error here
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

Não sei se entendi bem sua pergunta, mas o retorno é um objeto, com vários outros objetos dentro, então na variável **dia_do_mes** não precisa do **`{}`**, é só atribuir o valor de **`r`** a dia_do_mes, tbm aconselho a colocar dia_do_mes em uma variável ou constante:

```js
let dia_do_mes;

  fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/dhhvz')
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(r => {
    dia_do_mes = r;
    console.log(dia_do_mes)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    // Do something for an error here
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Como seu código é assíncrono, para garantir que o valor da variável está preenchido deve-se fazê-lo dentro do `then`. Atualmente há a opção de utilização do `async/await` também que garante que o código que executa uma função assíncrona aguarde a sua execução antes de continuar. Porém a instrução `await` (descrita acima) só pode ser utilizada em uma função com a instrução `async`, que determina que a mesma é "assíncrona" e que retornará uma promessa. Portanto seu código pode ser traduzido para:

```
const buscar = async() => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://api.myjson.com/bins/dhhvz');
    const r = response.json();
    console.log(r);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
};

buscar();
```

---

> [**Funções assíncronas**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas)
>
> A declaração **async function** define uma função assíncrona, que retorna um objeto [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/AsyncFunction).
>
> Você também pode definir funções assíncronas usando uma [expressão async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function).
>
> Quando uma função assíncrona é chamada, ela retorna uma [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Quando a função assíncrona retorna um valor, a `Promise` será resolvida com o valor retornado. Quando a função assíncrona lança uma exceção ou algum valor, a `Promise` será rejeitada com o valor lançado.
>
> Uma função assíncrona pode conter uma expressão [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), que pausa a execução da função assíncrona e espera pela resolução da `Promise` passada, e depois retoma a execução da função assíncrona e retorna o valor resolvido.